# Flask unable to capture 404 errors, as for some reason it returns 500 error whilst attempting to handle

Tags: python, flask, error-handling, http-status-code-404

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Apr/2021 10:38:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[2021-04-08 10:38:08,866] ERROR in app: Exception on /cap [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1926, in dispatch_request
    self.raise_routing_exception(req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1908, in raise_routing_exception
    raise request.routing_exception
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/ctx.py", line 350, in match_request
    result = self.url_adapter.match(return_rule=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1945, in match
    raise NotFound()
werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1816, in handle_user_exception
    return self.handle_http_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1744, in handle_http_exception
    return handler(e)
TypeError: not_found() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Apr/2021 10:38:08] "GET /cap HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Apr/2021 10:38:08] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

/cap is not a valid endpoint. When I Try to get it, it should surely return a error 404, as shown initially by the error message, and this block of code should work.

```py
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found():
    print('hit')
    return '400'
```

However, for whatever reason, it does not, and a 500 arrises which I cannot catch with Flask. I just want to account for URLs that are not valid endpoints and redirect to the home page as a consequence, but it seems this is not working.

Any help is hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

a lackluster fix, however

```py
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def catch_all(path):
    print(f'recieved invalid request attempt of /{path}')
    return render_template('redirect.html', reason='Unrecognised endpoint.')
```

does work using this app route as a 'catchall' to prevent any 404 errors in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This should work..

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(error):
    return render_template('errorpage.html'), 404
```

Also,

```
app.register_error_handler(404, page_not_found)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A 404 error handler must be able to take some parameters.

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(_):
    print('hit')
    return '400'
```

Comment: It's expected that error handler receive exception as positional argument, not just *"some parameters"* [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/errorhandling/#registering)

Comment: same error persists even having parsed e in as a parameter into the page_not_found() function

Comment: @syntax, check out docs, there're pretty detailed examples of handlers for different types of exceptions with explanation *(link in first comment)*.

Comment: same error? can you post the error trace?

Comment: yeh, exact same error with same traceback as above. will have a read of docs now. I did find a half working fix which should prevent 404s from occurring ever (see other comment), although it isn't really a fix. thanks for the help so far regardless Olvin and miquel.